# Which Entrust certificate do I need for Java-apns

Tags: ssl-certificate, apple-push-notifications, keystore

I am trying to do push messaging using the [java-apns library](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns).
I am currently trying to use it `.withSandboxDestination()` but I am getting an error saying: `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`.

I have read in quite a few places that it is probably due to a missing CA root certificate. The [Provider Communication with Apple Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1) says that:

> To establish a TLS session with APNs, an Entrust Secure CA root
>   certificate must be installed on the provider’s server. If the server
>   is running OS X, this root certificate is already in the keychain. On
>   other systems, the certificate might not be available. You can
>   download this certificate from the Entrust SSL Certificates website.

I am using a windows7 machine for my development phase. I opened mmc.exe and added the certificates snap-in (set up for "Computer" -  Q1: is this the right thing to do? ) and I can see under `Certificates (Local Computer)` -> `Trusted root certification authorities` -> `Certificates` the following two certificates by Entrust.net:

- `Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)`
- `Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority`

However, on the [Entrust.net site](https://www.entrust.net/downloads/root_request.cfm#) there are many more certificates...

Q2: Which of those certificates do I need?
Q3: Am I looking at the right place or maybe java within tomcat is not using my computer's certificates at all?
Q4: Is there a way for me to see the certificate used by apple's gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2195 ?

Any help is appreciated.